# In WCF, TransportWithMessageCredential security option will ignore HttpClientCredentialType?

Tags: c#, wcf

I read wcf [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpclientcredentialtype(v=vs.110).aspx), and know that

MSDN:

> Note that if SecurityMode is set to TransportWithMessageCredential, then the value of HttpClientCredentialType is **ignored**

really confusing about this, why the clientCredentialType is ignored ?

that means, if we set UserName to the following configuration clientCredentialType is doing nothing ???? so what is the default value of clientCredentialType when we set the TransportWithMessageCredential security mode ?

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" > 
           <message clientCredentialType="UserName" /> 
        </security>
```

Thanks !

Comment: @MickyD yes, why the security option ignore the HttpClientCredentialType ?? msdn tell me about that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpclientcredentialtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's very odd.  I just checked with what is essentially the _[WCF Bible](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489)_ and your snippet matches Mr Lowy's. _"If you like to use username and password credentials, simply configure the binding accordingly: (snippet matching yours)"_  Unless they changed something post .NET 4?  The only thing of course is that  you must set `proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName = ....`.  Are you doing that?